# Wrap workspace switching?

Tags: macos, application-switcher, spaces, fast-user-switching

Is there a setting that would allow me to wrap workspace switching? For example, what would I have to do to make it so that if I kept switching left I would eventually end up where I started.

I'm using Yosemite if that's relevant.

I have tried searching, however I think I may be using the wrong vocabulary since I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: In short, no there isn't